# How to flatten result of 1 to Many relationship join

Tags: c#, linq

I have a join

```cs
var result = from a in dbContext.As
   join b in dbContext.Bs on a.Id equals b.A.Id
   select { A = a, Ds = b.AList.Select(listItem => listItem.ObjectOfTypeD) }
```

how can I flatten the result so instead of list of `Ds` I get list of a single `D` linked with single `A` ?

Comment: It seems an awkward approach; your EF already understands how to link A and B (otherwise you wouldn't be able to say `b.A.Id`) so why not just leverage the built in join capability (`dbContext.Bs.Include(b => b.A).Select(...)`)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding another from:

```cs
var queryable = from a in dbContext.As
   join b in dbContext.Bs on a.Id equals b.A.Id
   from c in b.Children
   select new { a, c };
```

Or using `SelectMany`:

```cs
var queryable = (from a in dbContext.As
    join b in dbContext.Bs on a.Id equals b.A.Id)
    .SelectMany(t => t.b.Children.Select(c => new {t.a, c}));
```

Note that if you have correctly set up the relationships between the entities in the model usually there is no need to use manual joins, so you can try something like:

```cs
dbContext.Bs
   .SelectMany(b => b.AList
        .Select(li => new { b.A, D = li.ObjectOfTypeD }));
```